# jQuery delegate and custom events

Tags: jquery, jquery-delegate

I'm having issues binding a custom event to a delegate control

Any normal day I use the plugin like this

```
$(".galleryImage").swipe({
    swipeLeft: function (event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
        self.changeImageRight('swipe');
    },
    swipeRight: function (event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
        self.changeImageLeft('swipe');
    },
    threshold: 75 // px before events are triggered
});
```

If I bind it like this it works

```
$($galleryImageContainer).delegate('.galleryImage', 'click', function () {
    // ... magic stuff
});
```

But if I use swipe it doesn't

```
$($galleryImageContainer).delegate('.galleryImage', 'swipe', function () {
    // ... magic stuff
});
```

Is there a way to bind to custom events like this?

Thans

Comment: And does your custom events bubble ?

Comment: A thin, usually spherical or hemispherical film of liquid filled with air or gas, sometimes made out of soap as well ?

Comment: There are no other events connected to the events